# MAMP multiple VirtualHost

Tags: apache, mamp

I'm trying to add a VirtualHost to my MAMP.
So here are the steps that I did.

1. in /etc/hosts I add the following

   127.0.0.1 dev1.loc
   127.0.0.1 dev2.loc
2. in httpd.conf I added

   < VirtualHost *:80 >
       DocumentRoot "path"
       ServerName dev1.loc
   < /VirtualHost >

   < VirtualHost *:80 >
       DocumentRoot "path"
       ServerName dev2.loc
   < /VirtualHost >

So that almost work but not all the way.
Meaning, dev1.loc does work, but dev2.loc is pointing me to dev1.loc.

Do I need to do something special?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah got it resolved.
I also need to uncomment this line in httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

Thanks,
Tee